# How to multiply a function in a SetInterval on a addEventListener('click');

Tags: javascript

So I made this code (with the help of a tutorial) and I want to create the effect wherever I click.

The code does what it has to, but every time I do another click and call the 'drawParticle'-function, the process speeds up and less particles are been shown.
I think this is because I call on multiple setIntervals at once while JavaScript is single threaded. But how can I fix it?

```
var   canvas,
      c,
      particles,
      particleIndex,
      particleNum,
      w,
      h;

window.onload =function(){

    canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    c = canvas.getContext("2d");
    particles = {};
    particleIndex = 0;
    particleNum = 3;
    w = window.innerWidth;
    h = window.innerHeight;

    canvas.width = w;
    canvas.height = h;

    document.body.appendChild(canvas);

    c.fillStyle ="black";
    c.fillRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);

    canvas.addEventListener('click', drawParticle, false);
};

function drawParticle(e){

    function Particle(){
        this.x = e.clientX;
        this.y = e.clientY;
        this.vx = Math.random() * 10 - 5;
        this.vy = Math.random() * 10 - 5;
        this.gravity = 0.2;
        particleIndex++;
        particles[particleIndex] = this;
        this.id = particleIndex;
        this.life = 0;
        this.maxLife = Math.random() * 30 + 50;
        this.color = "rgb("+parseInt(Math.random()*255,10)+",0,0)";

      }

    Particle.prototype.draw = function(){

        this.x += this.vx;
        this.y += this.vy;

        if(Math.random() < 0.1 ){
           this.vx = Math.random() * 10 - 5;
           this.vy = Math.random() * 10 - 5;

        }


        //this.vy += this.gravity;
        this.life++;

        if(this.life >= this.maxLife){
         delete particles[this.id];
        }

        c.fillStyle = this.color;
        c.fillRect(this.x,this.y,10,10);
      };

    interval = setInterval(function(){
        //c.globalCompositeOperation ="source-over";
        c.fillStyle ="rgba(0,0,0,0.3)";
        c.fillRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);

        for (var i = 0; i < particleNum; i++){
         new Particle();
        }
        //c.globalCompositeOperation ="lighter";
        for (var i in particles){

           particles[i].draw();
        }
    },30);

};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're correct about the interval.  I'm not sure if this is the reaction you want but if you clear the interval before redrawing, things don't speed up.  Try something like:

```
var interval = null;
function drawParticle(e){

  if (interval) { 
    clearInterval(interval)
  }

  function Particle(){
    ...
```

There's a codepen here http://codepen.io/bunnymatic/pen/BjwVBM

UPDATE:

I've changed the code pen to include the new code which is included below.  The primary change was to make a `Particles` object which would hold the set of particles being drawn for each click.  By moving this collection of particles and their `particleIndex` seems to have solved the issue.  I suspect there was something strange about adding each element to the global `particles` list.  Now the `Particles` instance manages just the particles associated with that group.

I also took out `particleId` because it seemed unnecessary, though you may need to put it back in if it's useful for other stuff out side of this code.

Here's my updated code:

```
var   canvas,
c,
particleNum,
w,
h;

window.onload =function(){

  canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
  c = canvas.getContext("2d");
  particleNum = 3;
  w = window.innerWidth;
  h = window.innerHeight;

  canvas.width = w;
  canvas.height = h;

  document.body.appendChild(canvas);

  c.fillStyle ="black";
  c.fillRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);

  canvas.addEventListener('click', drawParticles, false);
};

function Particles() {
  this.particles = {};
  this.particleIndex = 0;
}

Particles.prototype.addParticle = function(particle) {
  this.particles[++this.particleIndex] = particle;
}

Particles.prototype.killDeadParticles = function() {
  for (var i in this.particles) {
    var particle = this.particles[i];
    if (particle.isDead()) {
      delete this.particles[i]
    }
  }
}

Particles.prototype.draw = function() {
  // draw particles
  for (var i in this.particles){
    this.particles[i].draw();
  }
  this.killDeadParticles();
}


function Particle(e){
  this.x = e.clientX;
  this.y = e.clientY;
  this.vx = Math.random() * 10 - 5;
  this.vy = Math.random() * 10 - 5;
  this.gravity = 0.2;
  this.life = 0;
  this.maxLife = Math.random() * 30 + 50;
  this.color = "rgb("+parseInt(Math.random()*255,10)+",0,0)";
  // console.log('new particle', particleIndex);
}

Particle.prototype.isDead = function() {
  return (this.life >= this.maxLife);
}

Particle.prototype.draw = function(){

  this.x += this.vx;
  this.y += this.vy;

  if(Math.random() < 0.1 ){
    this.vx = Math.random() * 10 - 5;
    this.vy = Math.random() * 10 - 5;

  }

  //this.vy += this.gravity;
  this.life++;

  c.fillStyle = this.color;
  c.fillRect(this.x,this.y,10,10);
};

function drawParticles(e){

  var particles = new Particles(e);

  setInterval(function(){
    //c.globalCompositeOperation ="source-over";
    c.fillStyle ="rgba(0,0,0,0.3)";
    c.fillRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);

    for (var i = 0; i < particleNum; i++){
      var particle = new Particle(e);
      particles.addParticle(particle);
    }
    //c.globalCompositeOperation ="lighter";
    particles.draw();
  },30);

};
```

Comment: That's step in the right direction, but is there a possibility to keep every interval running on every click? So that the Particles keep being drawn?

Comment: I'll try again.  So you want it to act the way your initial code is working, except that it doesn't speed up with each click, right?